# Email to a friend in Product view page is not working

Tags: php, email, magento

There is Email to a Friend (a kind of Referring to a friend) functionality in Magento. You can see the "Email to a Friend" link in Product view page.

Whenever I try to send email to a friend from this, I get the following error:-

**Some emails was not sent**

I have configured **Host** from **System -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> System -> Mail Sending Settings**.

I have also configured **SMTP** and **sendmail_from** in **php.ini** file.

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: Problem solved. Sorry, but the problem was with another module which I was using. This module was overriding SendFriend Model class (Mage_Sendfriend_Model_Sendfriend).

Comment: I don't want to delete this question as this can be a help for someone with similar situation/problem. I want to close this question but in the option list of "Why should this question be closed?".. I don't find the exact option that could fit in this question's situation. Any help guys?

Comment: Post your update as a new answer so you can accept it as correct. The big green checkmark will let others know what resolved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

The problem was with another module which I was using. This module was overriding SendFriend Model class (**Mage_Sendfriend_Model_Sendfriend**).

My problem will be helpful to those who fall on similar type of situation.

> When the core code seems to be working
>   well or when you haven't changed any
>   core code.. even then you are getting
>   problem in Magento default
>   functionality.

The reason can be some local or community module overriding the core classes.